# "Acknowledgment [to?] those who helped me"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am writing the *Acknowledgment* section of my thesis. Because of the etiquette and because I tend to be verbose, this section is rather long.

Thus, I would like to divide this section into subsections. The latter would show what category of person is acknowledged in this section. 
Here is an excerpt:

> ## Acknowledgment
>
> ### ... [to] those who supervized me
>
> I am grateful to Professor Doe...
>  I would also like to thank Erika Musterman...
>
> ### ... [to] those who helped me
>
> Jane and John did so much for me. May they here be thanked.

**Question:** Is the preposition "to" the correct one in this situation?

Comment: Your department may have their own *Style Manual* for formatting and writing a thesis, have you checked there?

Comment: @Peter Of course—I'm asking a question here only because I've not found relevant answers in my available documentation. However, I'm not quite sure how this is relevant for my question. This question indeed focus on the choice of a preposition in the sentence: "*Acknowledgement [for/to] those who helped me*". You can forget about the thesis, and think of the sentence: "*I want to express my acknowledgment [to/for]...*" The context just explains why I want to phrase this sentence like this.

Comment: Yes. One generally offers acknowledgement **to** people.  You may not have to use the word "to" however, as it's kind of obvious.  You could title the section "Acknowledgements" (in the plural), then simply list the people to whom you are thankful.

Comment: Note "May they here be thanked" is not idiomatic, at least not in this century.  Perhaps "and to whom I am eternally grateful".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would generally use "**acknowledgement to**" with people, groups of people and organizations *(to whom?)* and "**acknowledgement for**" with objects, events, situations and procedures *(for what? for whom?)*.

- I offer special **acknowledgement to** my dissertation committee (Dr, Raney, Dr. Arpan, Dr. DuBard, and Dr. Everhart)
- An **acknowledgement for** production is generally not required in a transfer of part of registered land.
- The author makes grateful **acknowledgement to** the following organisations and individuals.
- Over a two year period, the school received much **acknowledgement for** its capacity to improve.

> One should also consider the difference between "**acknowledgment**" (American spelling) and "**acknowledgement**" (British spelling).

You can look at [**http://acknowledgementsample.com**](http://acknowledgementsample.com) for templates of the acknowledgement section.

By looking at a few templates I can tell you that "**to**" is omitted:

1. [**Writing acknowledgement in scientific papers and publications**](http://acknowledgementsample.com/writing-acknowledgement-scientific-papers-publications/)
2. [**Acknowledgements writing guidelines**](http://acknowledgementsample.com/acknowledgements-writing-guidelines/)